# Scrollable background image covering only some sections of the page

Tags: html, css, grid, background-image

I would need your help to solve this issue.

I am developing a personal project and I created a classic index.html file linked with an external index.css.

I used the css grid to create different inner sections, each page having a different inner grid structure.

So here it is how my index page structure is like:

-top left: div with a logo. The logo is itself an anchor link which redirects to the homepage/landing page;

-top right, next to the logo: div with a navbar, with 3/4 links (about, contact, etc.)

-main page (center): below the two upper divs, I have a main area, covering the whole screen size with some text;

-second page (below center): below the main page, with images and text (you need to scroll down the page);

-bottom: footer.

Now my intention would be to put a background-image which covers only the first 3 sections (logo, navbar and main area), leaving the other areas on their own. They will have a different color and content.

Important is that the background-image should scroll down along with the page and should not remain sticky and fixed in its own position. It is supposed to look like as if it were the background-image of the main page in the center, but it is not.

If I put the background-image only in the main page, then the top divs are imageless and I want the background-image to cover the two upper divs too. If i put the same image into these 3 main divs individually, then I risk the images to overlay and it is quite ugly to see and hard to manage when resizing and with media queries.

Now I am using the css-grid to make it responsive and just plain css. Is there a way to create this type of effect with just css or do I need mandatorily a css framework (bootstrap, etc) or to change the structure differently?

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="grid-container">
       
       <!-- LOGO AREA-->
        <div class="logo">

            <div class="logo">
                <a href="Index.html"><img id="logo" src="pic/white_logo.png" alt="logo"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        
        <!-- NAVBAR AREA-->
        
        <div class="navbar">

            <ul class="nav-list">
                <a class="list" href="about.html"><li>about</li></a>
                <a class="list" href=""><li>skills</li></a>
                <a class="list" href=""><li>contact</li></a>
             </ul>


        </div>

<!-- MAIN PAGE AREA-->
        <div class="main-page">

            <h2>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem Ipsum</h2>
            <a id="learn-more-button" href="">LEARN MORE</a>


        </div>

        <!-- SECOND PAGE -->

        <div class="second-page"></div>
<!-- FOOTER -->

        <div class="footer"></div>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

body {
  font-family: Montserrat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  color:white;
  background-image: url(pic/background1.jpg);
}


.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 0.6fr 1.9fr;
    height:150vh;
    grid-template-rows: 0.5fr 2.5fr 1.3fr 0.4fr;
    gap: 0px 0px;
    grid-template-areas:
      "logo navbar"
      "main-page main-page"
      "second-page second-page"
      "footer footer";
  }
  

  
  /* LOGO AREA*/


.logo {
    grid-area: logo;
  
  }
  
  #logo {
    padding:2rem 0 0 2rem;
  }
  
  
  
  /* NAVBAR AREA*/
  .navbar {
    grid-area: navbar;
    padding-left: 25rem;
  padding-top:2.5rem;
  }


  
   li {
    margin-right: 2.5rem;
  display: inline;
  list-style-type: none;
   }
  
   a {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
     color:white;
     text-decoration: none;
   }
  
  

/* MAIN-PAGE AREA*/

.main-page { 
    grid-area: main-page;
  
  }
  
  
  h2 {
    width:50rem;
    margin-top:15rem;
    padding-bottom: 3.5rem;
    margin-left:1.25rem;
  }
  
  
  #learn-more-button {
    border:0.063rem solid white;
    color:white;
    padding:0.938rem;
    margin-left:20rem;
    }
  
    #learn-more-button:hover{
  background-color: white;
  color:black;
  transition: 0.6s;
    }
  

    /* SECOND AREA */
  
 
    .second-page { 
        grid-area: second-page; 
    }
 
 
    /* FOOTER AREA*/

  .footer { 
  grid-area: footer;

}
```

I totally appreciate any kind of help and thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to take that 3 dives in one more div
and to that parent  div give the background image and remove background attachment fixed..
try this ..

css  (add this style in your code):

```
 .one {
            background: url(background1.jpg) no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
        }
```

HTML :

```
  <div class="grid-container">
        <div class="one">
            <!-- LOGO AREA-->
            <div class="logo">

                <div class="logo">
                    <a href="Index.html"><img id="logo" src="pic/white_logo.png" alt="logo"></a>
                </div>
            </div>


            <!-- NAVBAR AREA-->

            <div class="navbar">

                <ul class="nav-list">
                    <a class="list" href="about.html">
                        <li>about</li>
                    </a>
                    <a class="list" href="">
                        <li>skills</li>
                    </a>
                    <a class="list" href="">
                        <li>contact</li>
                    </a>
                </ul>


            </div>

            <!-- MAIN PAGE AREA-->
            <div class="main-page">

                <h2>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem Ipsum</h2>
                <a id="learn-more-button" href="">LEARN MORE</a>


            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- SECOND PAGE -->

        <div class="second-page"></div>
        <!-- FOOTER -->

        <div class="footer"></div>
    </div>
```

OUTPUT :

[change width of parent and child divs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzvLY.png)

Comment: Thanks. I will try that as soon as possible and let you know.

Comment: I have tried. The only problem is that, I don't have that big container ".one" into my grid template and I don't know how to insert it, This creates some troubles when resizing. The navbar remains sticky and doesn't flex anymore.